# What is a "verification" in Firebase Auth pricing?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

The [Firebase Auth pricing](https://firebase.google.com/pricing) says it is $0.06/verification for overseas users. What is a verification?

Is this just verifying their email address one time or is this verifying they are signed in for every API request they make from the app?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only priced part of Firebase Authentication is for phone authentication (indicated as <kbd>Phone Auth</kbd> in the page you linked), which consists of sending a text/SMS message to the user with a verification code/one-time password.

When you use this authentication method, you pay for completed verifications, so when the user has completed signing in to Firebase Authentication through the code that was sent in the SMS message.

So you don't pay for verifying an email address, nor for each API call you make, but only for completed verifications through the code that was sent in the SMS message.

If you don't want to risk every having to pay this, ensure that the phone authentication method is disabled in the [Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/authentication/providers) (as it is by default).